# List of lists using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I've been stuck for a while on some online learning I've been trying.

I need to create a list of empty lists using recursion.

The strange thing is that I thought that I understood a factorial algorithm (which there is lots of help for) but not with this and as a result it always just returns the single [ ].

For example if `n=4` then I would expect `[[ ], [ ], [ ] ,[ ]]`

```
def listOfLists(n):

    lists = []

        if i <= 1:
            return lists
        else:
            lists += lists.append([])
            listOfLists(n-1)
```

Comment: This is where I've got myself into a twist. On this particular attempt I tried starting with the for but on my other attempts it just started with if statements.

Comment: Thanks BoarGules but I have to use recursion in this particular method.

Comment: I nearly didn't post as I've heard lots of negative things about the responses on SO. So before I posted I read this and set me at ease.  https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: SO can certainly be welcoming, all we ask is that users put a certain amount of effort into solving the problem on their own before coming here, additionally providing all the information needed in the question itself, including code, the problem encountered, what you've tried, what you're trying to do, what results you expect, what results you get instead, etc. If you're interested I suggest you read Jon Skeet's blog post about [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (It's quite a read but has some interesting points in it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use the response of your recursive call, try to understand this code (I've tried to keep the form similar to yours):

```
def listOfLists(n):
    lists = [[]]
    if n <= 1:
        return lists
    else:
        return lists + listOfLists(n-1)
```

This written "dry-run" may help you understand it (for `listOfLists(3)`):

```
Call - listOfLists(3)
 Call - listOfLists(2)
  Call - listOfLists(1)
  Return [[]] # From listOfLists(1)
 Return [[]] + [[]] # From listOfLists(2)
Return [[]] + [[],[]] # From listOfLists(3)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works a treat, I'm now going to go through all my previous versions to determine where I was going so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function was already given in others answer, I want to explain why your code do not work as expected.
Culprit is that line:

```
lists += lists.append([])
```

instead it should be:

```
lists.append([])
```

or alternatively:

```
lists = lists+[[]]
```

Note that `.append` method add element at end of `list` and `return`s `None`, consider following example:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x.append(4)
print(y) #None
print(x) #[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As you might see `append` method altered `x` list and `y` is `None`, not `[1,2,3,4]`. Nonetheless your function, even after described repair would not be *recursive* function.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant for your consideration.  This uses an additional argument with a default value.

```
def listOfLists(n, lists = []):
    if n > 0:
        lists.append([])
        return listOfLists(n-1, lists)
    else:
        return lists

print(listOfLists(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use recursion to solve a problem better suited to repetition, you can do this. I've kept as close to your original as I reasonably could.

```
def listOfLists(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return []
    else:
        return [ [] ] + listOfLists(n-1)

>>> listOfLists(4)
[[], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def listOfLists(n,lists=[]):
    lists.append([])
    if n == 1:   
        return

    listOfLists(n-1,lists)
    return lists

print (listOfLists(4))
```

result: [[], [], [], []]

Answer (score 0):

There are great recursive answers posted, however, it is also possible to use generators with recursion:

```
def listOfLists(n):
   if n:
     yield []
     yield from listOfLists(n-1)

print(list(listOfLists(4)))
```

Output:

```
[[], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Thank you but I haven't got to something like this yet but no doubt it will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
def listoflist_func(n, currentList=[]):
    if n < 0:
        return "Error: n must be > 0"
    elif n==0:
        return currentList
    else:
        currentList.append([])
        return listoflist_func(n-1, currentList)


print listoflist_func(4)
```

Result is :

```
[[], [], [], []]
```

Best

Comment: Thanks Macouille but I have to use recursion in this particular method.

Comment: Updated my answer, srry